# Custom layer needs changing tf.keras.input empty tensor into numpy ndarray - 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' error

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.7, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I've written a `tf.keras` custom layer in which I used some functions that work only with `numpy` arrays, so when I try to use my layer in a model with tf.keras.Input, the functions raise an error: `input data must be a numpy ndarray.`

`tf.keras.backend.eval(x)` and `x.numpy()` both results in error: `'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'` , even though eager execution is enabled.

using `sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()` and `sess.run(x)` gives: The Session graph is empty. Add operations to the graph before calling `run()`

Here's a sample model I'm testing with:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(48,48,1))
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)

# y = tf.keras.backend.eval(x)

# init_op = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
# with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
#    sess.run(init_op)
#    y = sess.run(x)

# y = x.numpy()

z = Mylayer.My_custom_layer()(y)
outputs = z
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

The commented lines are what I've tested.

Is there anyway that I can convert this tensor input to `numpy` array before entering my custom layer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use numpy function for creating the computation graph in Keras or TensorFlow. and you should use equal built-in functions from tensorflow or keras. can you give the code for your costumeLayer?